# How to split received data from php ajax request and display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to receive two variables(say var1 is name and var2 is city) from another php file.

Using jquery ajax requests, its showing whole "data" in one string 
i.e data : name - city.

But i want to split both name,city separately and assign to different li elements in html.

How to do this? Please help..

Note: Names and cities i am taking from db in php. So multiples names and cities will be there. I think find alone cant be used.

Comment: if you're in control of this json-generating-php, why not have it generate the data properly in the first place? much easier to send over `{"name":"foo","city":"bar"}` rather than `"foo bar"`

Comment: Thank you very much Marc :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the PHP send your data in JSON by using something like:

```
$myData = ["name" => "foo", "city" => "bar"];
$dataToSend = json_encode($myData);
echo $dataToSend;
die();
```

You can now receive that data in your Javascript by doing something like:

```
$.getJSON("myphp.php", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) JSON helped a lot and also i got another way by echoing along with html element output

Comment: Does JSON have big benefits of normal data requests from another php file?